# Storing session data in MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, session

In Laravel I want to save session data in the database. The database I am using is MongoDB. It works fine when I am using the session driver as a file, but as I changed it to database, on every request, it creates a new record in the session collection, leaving user_id null.

For example, when I hit the login route, a record was added to the session collection, and when I submitted the form, it led me to the 419 page, and another record was added to the session collection. Interestingly, when I tested the same functionality with MySQL, it worked fine.

I'm not sure if I've provided enough detail, and if I've made any mistakes, I apologize. Please, could someone help me figure out how to resolve this issue?

**Session.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

**database.php**

```
    'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'options' => [
                'appname' => 'homestead',
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: can you share your `session.php` and `database.php` part of code relating to mongodb?

Comment: No, you've not shared any information that we can use to help you. The session being created each time instead of being validated against the existing one could happen for any number of reasons, including programming errors, bugs, edge cases, etc. Post your code in a [**Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's also a good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's on-topic in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the post with the MongoDB section in the database.php file and the whole session.php file.

 I have implemented basic authentication, and everything is working fine. However, as soon as I switched to the session driver as the database, it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step-by-step guide on how to set up MongoDB as the session driver in a Laravel application:
**Step 1: Install MongoDB Package**

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

**Step 2: Configure MongoDB Connection**
Open your config/database.php file and add a new MongoDB connection configuration.

```
'mongodb' => [
    'driver'   => 'mongodb',
    'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE', 'your_database'),
    'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'options'  => [
        'database' => 'admin',
    ],
],
```

**Step 3: Configure Session Driver**
Now, open your config/session.php file and update the driver configuration to use the MongoDB driver:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'mongodb'),
```

**Step 4: Update Environment Configuration**
In your .env file, update the SESSION_DRIVER and other MongoDB-related environment variables:

```
SESSION_DRIVER=mongodb
MONGODB_HOST=localhost
MONGODB_PORT=27017
MONGODB_DATABASE=your_database
MONGODB_USERNAME=
MONGODB_PASSWORD=
```

**Step 5: Migrate Session Data**

```
php artisan session:table --connection=mongodb
php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations/mongodb --database=mongodb
```

**Step 6: Test**

```
// Storing session data
session(['key' => 'value']);

// Retrieving session data
$value = session('key');
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response,  I have implemented the steps again but facing same issue.

Comment: To avoid confusion, `jessengers/mongodb` has been officially adopted by MongoDB and is now `mongodb/laravel-mongodb`